# Using Web.Config to redirect from one page on a domain to a page on another

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, web-config, http-status-code-301

I have a content managed ASP.NET site that runs the same version of the site in different languages (e.g. mysite.com, mysite.fr, mysite.eu, etc). I have been asked to create a redirect from one page on our French site to a page on our European site, so  I fired up URL Rewrite within IIS and attempted to write a rule and map to do this. After failing this I attempted to write it into the Web.config file, but again to no avail.

To be clear, I need:

- `http://www.mysite.fr/publication/jobs.aspx` to redirect to
  `http://www.mysite.eu/jobs.aspx`
- `http://www.mysite.fr/sign-in.aspx`
  to redirect to `http://www.mysite.eu/sign-in.aspx`.

Does anyone know exactly how I can do this or whether this can be done on a ASP.NET site with multiple domains?

Comment: have you tried using Global.ascx file's Application_BeginRequest event for rewriting url?

Comment: I have, but as my site is content managed I am unable to provide valid virtual URL's.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using URL Rewrite.

Here's an example that I use.

```
<rule name="Redirect .co.uk" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
     <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^uk\.test\.com$" />
    </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.test.co.uk/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

This will check the the `{HTTP_HOST}` of the request, if it matches uk.test.com, redirect to the new url but keep the *page/folder path ({R:1}).*

Adding */publication/* makes things a little trickier, but it can be written into the original match (*something like. `(.*)\/publication\/(/*)` or something, my Regex aren't perfect :-)*).

HTH

Comment: This is almost exactly what I have already used, although I am only redirecting one page and it looks like this code doesn't have a mapping to target this page.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the URL Rewrites you've already tried, please?